# PHP global variable don't set via foreach

Tags: php, loops, variables, foreach

After I try to set `$mode` to 1, echo command prints me:

```
mode: 0 (see here)
before: 0
after: 1

mode: 0 (see here)
before: 0
after: 1
```

Why?

```
$generations = str_get_html($json['html'])->find('option');
$loop = true;
$tries = 1;
$mode = 0;
while ($loop && $tries > 0) {echo 'mode: '.$mode.' (see here)<br>';
    $loop = false;
    foreach ($generations as $generation) {
        ++$j;
        if ($j == 0) continue; // Пропускаем первый элемент спарсенного списка

        $params = array(
            // [0] - числовой ID, [1] - "человекопонятное" название
            'filter_brand' => $car[0],
            'filter_model' => $model[0],
        );

        if ($generation != null) {
            if ($mode == 0) {
                $generationn = array(trimNumber(trim($generation->getAttribute('value'))), trim($generation->plaintext));
                $params['filter_generation'] = $generationn[0];
                $carlist_plain = parse('http://podbor-akkumulyatora.ru/site/submit/?' . http_build_query($params));
                if (!$carlist_plain) die('Не удалось спарсить двигатели у поколения ('.$generationn[1].') модели ('.$model[1].') машины ('.$car[1].')');
            } else {
                // Not working
                $gen_a = $generation->find('a', 0);
                $generationn = array(trim($gen_a->href), trim($gen_a->plaintext));
                debug($generationn);
                //$carlist_plain = parse('http://podbor-akkumulyatora.ru/site/submit/?' . );
            }
        } else {
            $carlist_plain = parse('http://podbor-akkumulyatora.ru/site/submit/?' . http_build_query($params));
            if (!$carlist_plain) die('Не удалось спарсить двигатели у модели ('.$model[1].') машины ('.$car[1].')');
        }

        $carlist_plain = str_get_html($carlist_plain[0]);
        $carlist = $carlist_plain->find('.carlist ul li');
        if (count($carlist) < 1) {
            $generations = $carlist_plain->find('.generation ul li[itemprop="itemListElement"]');
            $loop = true;
            --$tries;
            echo 'before: '.$mode.'<br>';
            $mode = 1; // Not working
            echo 'after: '.$mode.'<br><br>';
            break;
        }

        // Handling $carlist here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Because in `else`  branch you set it to 0.

Comment: it may not meet the condition  in `if`

Comment: Actually code loop (`while`) running only one time and at that time value is 0:- https://eval.in/936347

Comment: the loop runs once because tries is only set to 1. The first time the loop runs, mode is 0 because that's it's starting value, so that's what you see. The loop never runs again because it $tries becomes 0.

Comment: Tries NOT becomes 0. I debugged it. You are not checked and downvote my question. I even COMMENTED `// else $mode = 0;`, it not runs. Always running ONLY and only `if` condition, `else` doesn't. And `while` calling not once, it called twice, so I get `mode: 0
mode: 0`

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar see updated code and question description

Comment: @AlivetoDie see updated code and question description

Comment: @u_mulder see updated code and question description

Comment: @ADyson see updated code and question description

Comment: what you are actually doing inside `if` by setting `mode=1`

Comment: So, what's the problem? If loop runs twice then your mode is not changed to 1.

Comment: @Mr.Andrew actually I looked at AliveToDie's link which shows the (earlier version of) code running, and it's very clear that the loop only runs once, you can see it clearly by the output which is generated. If it had executed twice, you would see two `<br>`s in the output.

Comment: @Mr.Andrew if you don't believe me, look at https://eval.in/936473 , it outputs the value of $tries explicitly for you to see. And I didn't downvote you, either.

Comment: Your current code (simplified to exclude the bits I can't execute) demonstrates identical behaviour: https://eval.in/936479 . As to _why_, well because that's the code you wrote. I don't know what else you want people to say. What were you expecting it to do instead?

Comment: @ADyson you are looking into unreal code. I wrote this as example. I shared new code in my question. Re-read it from top to bottom, please. And see about I get echo twice (in updated code), not once

Comment: @ADyson it's changing to `1`, but on next loop it somehow prints as `0`. See `before` and `after` in my description

Comment: @Mr.Andrew How is it getting to the second loop? It simply isn't possible, with the code as-is (even with your extra bits) for it to loop twice - even varying the $carlist and $generations lengths won't achieve it. See https://eval.in/937076 , https://eval.in/937078. You always set either $loop to false, or $tries to 0, either of which prevents a second loop. I've seen your answer but since you never said what you would consider to be the conditions for the code to "work", I have no idea if that makes a correct answer or not, so can't upvote

Answer (score 0):

It was very anomally, but I moved `$mode` out of **all** loops at all, and code now working